# drawing cylinder using vbo in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, draw, vbo

I am trying to draw cylinders using vbo. As I have understood, I need vertices and normal arrays to draw a cylinder using vbo, but I don't know how to specify those arrays. I need to find the content of those arrays.

Comment: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/ will show you how to do this.

Comment: What did you try? Where is the coding related issue? ... We're not here to do your work/research, you need to do that yourself!

Comment: type "vbo example" in google. Second result looks well, http://www.opengl.org/wiki/VBO_-_just_examples

Comment: @Vallentin I have code but since I gave the vertices and the normals wrongly, it produces sth nonsense. First, I thought vertices at the bottom and the top are the shape of a hexagon(I thought I can use these vertices to draw but that is not the case) so I have 12 vertices and 8 shapes right now.

Comment: @SAKrisT yes, I am able to draw shapes which can be generated using triangles, quads but I suppose this is not the case for a cylinder since it has no vertices.

Comment: Guys, I am not asking for code, I am just asking how to specify those vertices. Since the vertices are not clear to draw a cylinder.

Comment: @user1508716 read my comment again.

Comment: @Vallentin no need, I got my answer, It is written below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process of creating an array of triangles that represents a geometric object is called **tesselation**.

There are methods for triangulating parametric surfaces such as cylinders.

Another option is to draw a cylinder in a 3d modelling tool such as Blender, 3d studio max or Maya and then export a triangle mesh of your model and parse that file and thus load the model into your program.

Comment: As I understand,your first solution suggests that I hold the vertex array in a way that draw the cylinder using triangles. It will look like cylinder but the corners would be sharp

Comment: This is how it's always done in modern computer graphics. You can have different resolution (more or less vertices in the triangle mesh that makes up the cylinder). The more triangles you use to make up the cylinder the smoother it gets, until you can't even distinguish the triangles.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose it worked!, I was considering to increase the number of triangles before reading your comment, It made me confident about doing it.

Comment: Is there any way to smooth the edges?